# URL key for specified store already exists on Category edit in Magento in Magento 2.1.6

Tags: magento-2.1, category, save, url-key

I working on a project on which I get the error

> URL key for the specified store already exists

While editing category on store 2. I get this error only on **store 2 Arabic first category and also in its subcategories.**

I have surfed a lot. **According to github, it is bug of Magento**. However, I tried by truncating catalog_category_product_index and catalog_category_product. 
It works, but I cannot truncate it because of a large number of products in categories.
Is there any way to resolve this error?

https://github.com/magento/magento2/issues/6671

https://github.com/magento/magento2/issues/7298

https://github.com/magento/magento2/issues/3268

[image]

Comment: change `URL Key` key of category where you get this error. this will fix your issue

Comment: by default magento generate url key based on name and due to same name it happens

Comment: I changed but it doesn't work. I am getting error only in second store. Thanks @MineshPatel

Comment: make sure your new key is not there for any category :)

Comment: I am sure, i tried random strings :) @MineshPatel

Comment: or check `URL Rewrites` and search for that key

Comment: I did, even i truncated table url_rewrites :( @MineshPatel

Comment: and what is status of `Create Permanent Redirect for old URL` is checked ?

Comment: yes , it is checked @MineshPatel

Comment: hmm. try with unchecked if old url is not so important for you

Comment: else need to check code now as you said issue reported in github

Comment: post your result here after that

Comment: Checkbox is disabled in all stores... @MineshPatel

Comment: when you change `URL Key` you can change it

Comment: I tried it, but still it  doesn't works.. @MineshPatel

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have fixed this issue. And I have 2 solutions for that.

**The first one**: Clean up your database in table url_rewrite (Change the url_key of all category). You can write UpgradeData script for this solution.

**The second one**: Remove the duplication data when saving category.
This data is throw in method doReplace($urls) in \vendor\magento\module-url-rewrite\Model\Storage\DbStorage.php file.

```
protected function doReplace($urls)
    {
        foreach ($this->createFilterDataBasedOnUrls($urls) as $type => $urlData) {
            $urlData[UrlRewrite::ENTITY_TYPE] = $type;
            $this->deleteByData($urlData);
        }
        $data = [];
        foreach ($urls as $url) {
            $data[] = $url->toArray();
        }
        $this->insertMultiple($data);
    }
```

After debugging, I found out $data variable have duplicate record. If you want this method to work without any errors, rewrite this method above to:

```
protected function doReplace($urls)
{
    foreach ($this->createFilterDataBasedOnUrls($urls) as $type => $urlData) {
        $urlData[UrlRewrite::ENTITY_TYPE] = $type;
        $this->deleteByData($urlData);
    }
    $data = [];
    $storeId_requestPaths = [];
    foreach ($urls as $url) {
        $storeId = $url->getStoreId();
        $requestPath = $url->getRequestPath();
        // Skip if is exist in the database
        $sql = "SELECT * FROM url_rewrite where store_id = $storeId and request_path = '$requestPath'";
        $exists = $this->connection->fetchOne($sql);

        if ($exists) continue;

        $storeId_requestPaths[] = $storeId . '-' . $requestPath;
        $data[] = $url->toArray();
    }

    // Remove duplication data;
    $n = count($storeId_requestPaths);
    for ($i = 0; $i < $n - 1; $i++) {
        for ($j = $i + 1; $j < $n; $j++) {
            if ($storeId_requestPaths[$i] == $storeId_requestPaths[$j]) {
                unset($data[$j]);
            }
        }
    }
    $this->insertMultiple($data);
}
```

If you want to get more details, please read my comment in:
https://github.com/magento/magento2/issues/7298

Hope this will help you.

Comment: Never try at live website, it will break your products links and images

Comment: @ToanTam Facing issue in child category. child category not updated parent key there is showing old key of parent category. Let me know if any idea ?